# Use nested class with EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I use EF core to manipulate base and I have class Customer

```
public class Customer
{
        public Customer(string fullname, Address address)
        {
            this.Id = IdGenerator.GetId();

            this.Fullname = fullname;
            this.Address = address;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

And I have Address class

```
public class Address
{
        public Address(int index, string country, string city, string building, string apartment)
        {
            this.Index = index;
            this.Country = country;
            this.City = city;
            this.Building = building;
            this.Apartment = apartment;
        }

        public int Index { get; set; }

        public string Country { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Building { get; set; }

        public string Apartment { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add customer in db I get error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'oop_backend.Models.Address' to type 'System.String'.
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelValidationContext validationContext)
```

I can't understand what I need to do to fix this error

Comment: Please use the [entity-framework-core] tag and additionally an [ef-core-xx] tag indicating the version you're in. That said, you seem to have data annotations, if so, please don't remove them from the code you show here.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with EF Core. It's thrown by the MVC validators. I suspect if you posted the *full* exception text you'd see it was thrown by MVC when a client makes a call to an action that expects a `Customer`. Please post the *full* exception text and the code that throws

Comment: at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: this is the end of the error